# mvn -v works in Git Bash but not in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, maven, cmd, maven-3, git-bash

Trying to do basic Maven configuration on Windows 8. Simply testing with command `mvn -v`. `mvn -v` works when using Git Bash, but does not work with Windows cmd.

Here are my environment variables:

```
$PATH: /C/Users/<username>/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin:/C/Progra~1/Java/jdk-12.0.2/bin

$JAVA_HOME: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-12.0.2

$M2_HOME: C:\Users\<username>\apache-maven-3.6.1

$MAVEN_HOME: C:\Users\<username>\apache-maven-3.6.1
```

Maven Version: 3.6.1

Output of `mvn -v` in Git Bash:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-04T14:00:29-05:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\<username>\apache-maven-3.6.1
Java version: 12.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-12.0.2
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Output of `mvn -v` in the Windows Command Prompt:

```
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Because of this I also have trouble using Maven in the Intellij terminal. I've messed around with environment variables for about an hour or so but I continue to have issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-x-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I configured my environment variables incorrectly. I went over and made sure to use backslashes `\` instead of forward slashes. Also I had colons `:` separating paths instead of the correct semi-colon `;`.